# How to get new line in v-text

Tags: vue.js

I want to het new line in `v-text` vuejs. There are two data. I want to show them in separate lines using one `<p>`. I tried it in below mentioned way. But it was not successful. How can I do this in vuejs.

Tried code:

```
<p class="mew-cls" v-text="`FName: ${arr.fname} \n Lname: ${arr.lname}`"></p>
```

Expected output:

```
FName: ZZZ
Lname: MMM
```

Current output:

```
FName: ZZZ \n Lname: MMM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use v-html instead.
This is easier since you can format the html inserted as desired.

```
<p class="mew-cls" v-html="`FName: ${arr.fname} <br> Lname: ${arr.lname}`"></p>
```